# Convert MATLAB code to R

Tags: r, matlab

Is there a tool for converting [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) code to R?

I have a lot of code that needs to be converted from MATLAB to R. It doesn't have to be accurate, but it will be helpful in giving a head start.

Comment: For simple programs you can try this new package: https://cran.r-project.org/package=matconv

Answer (score 17):

Paul Gilbert provides a rough [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) script that could get you started (he claims it will convert about 80% of the way) on the [R mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-October/025532.html):

```
#!/bin/csh
cp $1 $2
ex -s $2 <<eof
   g/%/s//#/g
   g/function\(..*\)=\(..*\)(\(..*\)/s//\2 <-function( \3 { \1/
   g/end/s//   } #/
   g/for\(..*\)=\(..*\):\(..*\)/s//for ( \1 in \2 : \3 ) {/
   g/_/s//./g
   g/;/s///g
   g/==/s//@@/g
   g/=/s//<-/g
   g/@@/s//==/g
   g/zeros(/s//matrix(0,/g
   g/ones(/s//matrix(1,/g
   g/eye(/s//diag(1,/g
   g/\/s//solve(,)/g
   g/fsolve('\(..*\)'/s//ms(~\1 /g
   g/param(\(..*\))/s//param[ \1 ] /g
   g/var(\(..*\))/s//var[ \1 ] /g
   g/mod1(\(..*\)/s//mod1[ \1 /g
   wq
eof
```

Answer (score 9):

No there is no easy conversion. Some will translate nearly exactly, some will translate only with great pain and suffering. At least you'll be using R though! Start here to work out analogous functions and syntax:

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/R-and-octave.txt

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Hiebeler-matlabR.pdf

When you get stuck please ask specific questions here. This is really too vague as it stands, though those reference cards will help with getting started.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to translating the code would be to call MATLAB from within R, using the [RMatlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/index.html) package.

I have not tried RMatlab, but the package description states:

> This package provides methods to read
>   and write MAT files. It also makes it
>   possible to communicate (evaluate
>   code, send and retrieve objects etc.)
>   with Matlab v6 or higher running
>   locally or on a remote host.

Comment: For Windows, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695105/call-r-scripts-in-matlab/6933492#6933492

Comment: @user236215 both R and RMatlab run on windows.

Comment: I think that `R.Matlab` package will read Matlab `.mat` files, which are basically data files, but it won't help you with translating code from `.m` files.

Comment: @GeekOnAcid you are correct, but it provides an interface to MATLAB, so that MATLAB can evaluate the code.

Comment: The correct name is R.matlab, this is de rcran URL: 

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Please see the comments on this issue:
URL:https://mandymejia.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/three-ways-to-use-matlab-from-r/

She mentions several options:

Option 1: Run a single MATLAB command at a time using system()

Option 2: Use R.matlab to send code to the MATLAB server

Option 3: Write an entire MATLAB program using writeLines() and run using system()