# Call R scripts in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

Is it possible to call R scripts in a MATLAB program? How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

You can use R in **batch mode**. If R is in your path, then you can call from MATLAB:

```
system('R CMD BATCH infile outfile');
```

will run the code in infile and place output in the outfile.

EDIT:
You can also give it a try with another approach using a R package [rscproxy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rscproxy/index.html) and R(D)COM Server, described [here](http://neurochannels.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-run-r-code-in-matlab.html).

Comment: nice (and confusing) that the matlab comand is also called system() - bonus points for the first R/matlab expression that performs the same task from either language . . .

Comment: exactly . . . system('RScript -e "matlab"'); w00t

Comment: As stated, this solution fails.  I get the message 'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. I tested to make sure that R.exe boots from cmd.  It does.  I added the path where R is stored.  Still no luck.  Running

system('"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH myRfile.R');

however, does work.  Another problem arises: if I save a string 

Rpath = "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\R.exe"

and run

system('Rpath CMD BATCH myRfile.R');

I get the message 'Rpath' is not recognized.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

After using R(D)COM and Matlab R-link for a while, I do not recommend it. The COM interface has trouble parsing many commands and it is difficult to debug the code. I recommend using a system command from Matlab as described in the 
[R Wiki](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:callingr:matlab).

Answer (score 3):

`system` is almost definitely the way to go, as described in other answers.  For completeness, you could also use MATLAB's capability to run Java code, and [JRI](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/) or [RCaller](http://www.mhsatman.com/rcaller.php) to call R from Java.  Similarly, you can use MATLAB's capability for running .NET code and [R.NET](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  On Windows, I have done a lot of this via the [Matlab R-link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5051-matlab-r-link) and then [R(D)COM server on the R side](http://cran.r-project.org/contrib/extra/dcom/).

It works beautifully for passing commands and data back and forth.  Calling R via the OS is feasible, but then you have to deparse (write) and parse (load) data passed between them.  This is tedious and no fun.  Especially if you are much data around.  It also means that you lose state on the R side and every invocation is just like the first time.

On Linux or another OS, or even for more general usage, I'd now try Rstudio as a server -- see http://www.rstudio.org/docs/server/getting_started for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `system` command to execute R scripts.  Something like the following:

```
[status] = system('R CMD BATCH [options] script.R [outfile]')
```

where [options] are the options your send to the R interpreter, and [outfile] is your output file.

Answer (score 1):

Another way [RWiki recommended](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips%3acallingr%3amatlab):

```
 CurrentDirectory=strrep(pwd,'\','/');
 eval(['!C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin/Rscript "' CurrentDirectory '/Commands.R"'])
```

Comment: This only works if the E executable is in a Folder without spaces, this would work in case there are spaces in the location (e.g. in the Windows case where R is installed in 'Program Files': evalc(['!' '"' r '"' ' ' '"' rcd '"' '/CommandR.R']); Here r is the location of the \bin\Rscript.exe and rcd is the location of the /CommandR.R file

Comment: @jmp111 Actually, I don't recommend installing R executables in a folder with any blank in its name because some of the commands would not work in Windows.

Comment: Which is what the trick with '"' is avoiding, the section between the two '"' is read as a string (which can contain spaces) instead of as a directory (which, as we both mentioned gives errors in Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You can run command line functions in matlab using the `unix` command. The easiest way would probably be to set up an R script which outputs results to a text file, run the script in matlab using the `unix` command, and then (in matlab) verify that the file exists and load it up.