# How to call R code from MATLAB while passing in-memory data and getting result again in-memory only?

Tags: r, matlab

I have a `matlab` and `R` code. `R` code takes `training_dataset`, `test_datapoint` and returns `0` or `1` based on model built and tested on passed data. I know a way to run `R` code by running system commands from `Matlab` but that requires data to be passed through a file. Is there a way to pass in-memory `Matlab` data (say a `Matlab` variable) to `R` script and get the result back (again in another `Matlab` variable) without having to write to the disk?

**Update** : Please note that I want to achieve this using some in-memory data structure and not through reading / writing files (as explained in the question referred to as duplicate of).

Comment: I guess not. Put your data in a text file and the ouput in another text file and then just read it in matlab.

Comment: Using Java, .NET or COM in between does not require to transport the data via files, please check these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6695633/2732801 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6933492/2732801 If you see any problems with these answers (I never used it) please explain and I will take a closer look at it.