# Call R script from MatLab - Error

Tags: r, windows, matlab, cmd

I would like to call an R script, say `myRfile.R`, from `MatLab`. I am using a `Windows 10` machine with `MatLab 2017a` and `R-3.4.2`. I use the `system` command as suggested in a previous [stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695105/call-r-scripts-in-matlab)  The solution is to do the following:

1. Add path to the installation location of `R`.  In my case, I write
   `addpath C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin`.
2. Ensure that the R script is in the working directory (or a path).
3. Call the function `system('R CMD BATCH myRfile.R')`.

I, however, get the error flag = 1 and the following is printed in the command window:

> 'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
>   operable program or batch file.

I checked to make sure that I can run `R` from cmd by navigating to the appropriate file and calling `R.exe`.  If, instead, I call `system` via:

> system('"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH
>   myRfile.R');,

then the script is executed correctly (no error).  Therefore, I have found a solution to my problem.  I, however, would like to define the string

> Rpath = "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\R.exe"

at the start of my program and run the command

> system('Rpath CMD BATCH myRfile.R');

This returns a similar error as before:

> 'Rpath' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
>   operable program or batch file.

Questions:

1. Why does the command `system('R CMD BATCH myRfile.R')` not work for me?
2. Why does the `system` command work if I write the directory for `R` directly as a string, but it does not work if I pass a string via `Rpath` to it?

Comment: Putting `‘Rpath’` in the middle of the string does not pass the string in any programming language that I’m aware of. Use `sprintf` to generate the string argument to `system`.

Comment: When you added R to the system path, did you restart matlab? Does `getenv('PATH')` include the R directory? (Does [Matlab's "run external commands"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html) page work for you?

Comment: @excaza `system('sprintf(Rpath) CMD BATCH Rum_81_genB_VtoH.R')` does not work.  It returns the error 'sprintf' is not a recognized...

Comment: You have to use `sprintf` to *make* the string argument to `system`, not put it inside

Comment: Also, `addpath` does not do anything to your system path, which is what `system` uses.

Comment: @r2evans I tried `setenv('C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin')`  with and without restarting `MatLab`.  In both cases, `getenv('PATH')` does not yield the directory where `R` is stored.

Comment: @excaza Can you please give an example?

Comment: That's not how `setenv` works, check the link I sent. (Hint: you set a value but to which environment variable should it be written?)

Comment: @r2evans Gotcha -- I write: `path1 = getenv('PATH');`
and
`path1 = [path1 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64'];`
and
`setenv('PATH', path1)`
Now the path to `R` is in the environment directory.  However, I still get the error when I run:
`system('R CMD BATCH Rum_81_genB_VtoH.R');`

Comment: @r2evans  Found the problem.  It works if I set the path to `'C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-34~1.2\bin\x64'` rather than `'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64'`.

Comment: Nice ... so *both* `matlab` and `R` have problems with spaces in paths. Kinda makes you wonder what's going on under the hood?

Comment: Nothing is going on under the hood, MATLAB and R pass the literal string to the OS. Windows requires paths with spaces in them to be wrapped in quotes, which you haven’t done.

Comment: have you tried using `Rscript.exe`?

Comment: @excaza Thanks for pointing that out.  The following also works: `path1 = getenv('PATH');`,   `path1 = [path1 '"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64"'];` and `setenv('PATH', path1)`.

Comment: @tao.hong Can you explain?  How do you call `Rscript.exe` from `MatLab`?  What is the advantage of `Rscript` vs `R CMD BATCH`?  The following article says that `Rscript` saves directly to `STDOUT` and does not echo input statements. 
 `R CMD BATCH`, on the other hand, does not save to `STDOUT` and echoes input lines.  Do these imply that `Rscript` is more efficient?
  http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/working-with-r-on-a-cluster/

Comment: @MattT, I think `Rscript` is newer to `R CMD BATCH`.https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218012917-How-to-run-R-scripts-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 3):

Building off @r2evans comments, the solution is to use `setenv` rather than `addpath`, since `system` uses the system paths to search for files.  The space between `Program` and `Files` is also problematic for the `system` command.

Sample solution:

```
% Get the current set of system paths
path1 = getenv('PATH'); 
% Append directory for R to the system path    
path1 = [path1'C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-34~1.2\bin\x64']; 
% Update system path
setenv('PATH', path1) 
% Run the system command.
system('R CMD BATCH myRfile.R');
```

In general, one way to get the correct path open an instance of `R` and input the command `file.path(R.home())`.  For me, this returns `"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2". Finally, append`\bin\x64`.

@excaza pointed out that the string defining the path to `R` should be surrounded by `""` in order for `cmd` to properly interpret spaces.  Solution 2:

```
path1 = getenv('PATH'); 
% Append directory for R to the system path    
path1 = [path1'"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64"']; 
% Update system path
setenv('PATH', path1) 
% Run the system command.
system('R CMD BATCH myRfile.R');
```