# Convert a matlab toolbox into an R script for spectral analysis with the help of a matlab tutorial

Tags: r, matlab

I would like to do a spectral analysis for fluorescence data as it is done in this tutorial (the tutorial uses NIR data though):
http://www.models.life.ku.dk/sites/default/files/iToolbox_Manual.pdf

However, this spectral analysis is done in Matlab and I would like to do the same thing in R. I have started looking for R packages and I found the pls package. Unfortunately, my R skills are not such that I could convert the example in the tutorial into functional R code. Can someone with great R skills please help me out on this one.

The matlab toolbox, example data and the tutorial can be downloaded here:
http://www.models.kvl.dk/iToolbox

The R package "R.matlab" is needed to load the example (nirbeer) matlab data file.

Any direct help or linkage to other websites/posts is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not heard of any automated programs for cross-interpreting Matlab code into R. I think you may need to learn to use the packages in R that offer the equivalent facilities. (Or use the R-to-Matlab facilities if you have a Matlab license, or use Octave.) I'm remembering that @cbeleites is both an SO participant and involved in active R package development along those lines. I see a couple of packages when I do a search on "Beleites spectra".

http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/hyperSpec/doc/index.html

http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/ChemoSpec/doc/ChemoSpec.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are some attempts to automate some Matlab-to-R conversion, like the old-school bash script you can find on SO post [Convert MATLAB code to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527145/convert-matlab-code-to-r). In my experience it doesn't work that well for more complex code. I second @Dwin - you might have to do it the hard way. There is [a great document by David Hiebele](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Hiebeler-matlabR.pdf), that shows cross-references between Matlab and R. Also, I am wondering what aspects of spectral analysis you want to replicate in R? Package [signal processing](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/signal/html/00Index.html) might be useful in any case.

Comment: I'm just putting this comment so the question rises to the top on the Active list. This is an excellent response and I do not understand why the person that gave me an up-vote in the last couple of minutes did not also up-vote this response.