# R package available for "Adjusted Mutual Information"?

Tags: r

I am searching for a package to calculate the adjusted mutual information between two clusterings. I have only found some python code via google. Is there any built-in R package or function that can be clustering the data via mutual information?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link
https://github.com/defleury/adjusted_mutual_information

It says "contains code for the fast & parallelized calculation of **Adjusted Mutual Information (AMI)**, Normalized Mutual Information (NMI) and Adjusted Rand Index (ARI) between clusterings in R."

For small clusters, here are 3 functions. Function `f_rez()` takes as input 2 vectors in which numbers says the partition of that element and returns AMI. It takes about 30 s for 3 pairs of clusters of length N = 11.117, on a dual core non-parallel.

```
f_nij <- function(v1,v2,l1,l2){     #contingency table n(i,j)=t(i,j)
  m <- matrix(0,l1,l2)
  for (i in 1:length(v1)){
    m[v1[i],v2[i]] <- m[v1[i],v2[i]] +1
  }
  m
}

f_emi <- function(s1,s2,l1,l2,n){    #expected mutual information
  s_emi <- 0
  for(i in 1:l1){
    for (j in 1:l2){
      min_nij <- max(1,s1[i]+s2[j]-n)
      max_nij <- min(s1[i],s2[j])
      n.ij <- seq(min_nij, max_nij)   #sequence of consecutive numbers
      t1<- (n.ij / n) * log((n.ij * n) / (s1[i]*s2[j]))
      t2 <- exp(lfactorial(s1[i]) + lfactorial(s2[j]) + lfactorial(n - s1[i]) + lfactorial(n - s2[j]) - lfactorial(n) - lfactorial(n.ij) - lfactorial(s1[i] - n.ij) - lfactorial(s2[j] - n.ij) - lfactorial(n - s1[i] - s2[j] + n.ij))
      emi <- sum(t1*t2)
      s_emi <- s_emi + emi
    }
  }
  return(s_emi)
}

f_rez <- function(v1,v2){
  library(infotheo)
  s1 <- tabulate(v1);
  s2 <- tabulate(v2);
  l1 <- length(s1)
  l2 <- length(s2)
  N <- length(v1)
  tij <- f_nij(v1,v2,l1,l2)   #contingency table n(i,j)=t(i,j). this would be equivalent with table(v1,v2)
  mi <- mutinformation(v1,v2) #function for Mutual Information from package infotheo
  h1 <- -sum(s1*log(s1/N))/N
  h2 <- -sum(s2*log(s2/N))/N
  nmi <- mi/max(h1,h2)        # NMI Normalized MI
  emi <- f_emi(s1,s2,l1,l2,N) # EMI Expected MI
  ami <- (mi-emi)/max(h1,h2)  #AMI Adjusted MI
  return(c(nmi,ami))   
}
```

Comment: Hi, where do you use the variable tij?  You define tij <- f_nij(v1,v2,l1,l2)  but don't seem to use tij again anywhere.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/vinhnguyenx/softwares) a matlab code for Adjusted Mutual Information(AMI). And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527145/convert-matlab-code-to-r) thread on stackoverflow, it is possible to translate .m file into .r file, though this isn't trivial, at least it is a way to get a function of AMI for R.

The R package "CLUE" provided Normalized Mutual Information(NMI), a "less-good" version of AMI. According to this paper "A Novel Approach for Automatic Number of Clusters Detection in Microarray Data based on Consensus Clustering" by Nguyen Xuan Vinh and Julien Epps, it seems that the Adjusted Rand Index(ARI) is a good substitution of AMI.

Luckily for ARI, there are a few R packages that implemented this funciton, such as, RRand() funciton in Phyclust package, RandIndex() function in flexclust package, adjustedRandIndex() function in mclust package, and a.rand.index2() in clustergas package.

Hope this helps.